# Create new column from list using only the first string in the list

Tags: python

I have a column with several strings within a list. I want just the first string in the list in the new column. Example below.

```
['Fantasy', 'Young Adult', 'Magical']
['Romance', 'Mystery', 'Magical']
['Fiction', 'Young Adult', 'Magical']
```

Tried this but did not work for me.

```
new_genre = [df_BestBooks.genres.str.split(' ')[index][0]
for index in range(0, len(df_BestBooks))]
print(new_genre)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apply method with lambda

```
import pandas as pd

df_BestBooks = pd.DataFrame({'genres': [['Fantasy', 'Young Adult', 'Magical'], ['Romance', 'Mystery', 'Magical'], ['Fiction', 'Young Adult', 'Magical']]})

get_first_genre = lambda lst: lst[0]

df_BestBooks['new_genre'] = df_BestBooks['genres'].apply(get_first_genre)

print(df_BestBooks)
```

output:

```
                            genres new_genre
0  [Fantasy, Young Adult, Magical]   Fantasy
1      [Romance, Mystery, Magical]   Romance
2  [Fiction, Young Adult, Magical]   Fiction
```